# Mysql-Node pool - release connection error and Singleton in Node

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

configuration.js

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool  = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 10,
    host            : 'localhost',
    user            : 'root',
    password        : '',
    database        : 'test'
});

pool.getConnection( function(err, connection) {
    if (err) console.error('error connecting: ' + err.stack);
     return;
});
module.exports = pool;
```

user.js model file

```
var async = require("async");
var homePage = function HomePage( user_id ) {   
    this.user_id = user_id;
    this.db   = require('../config/configuration');
}
homePage.prototype.getCourse = function( callback ){
    var self = this;
    self.db.query(' my sql query ', [ self.user_id ], function (error, results, fields) {
        self.db.release();
        callback(err,results);
    });
};
```

I have exported my db connection here and I require that module(configuration.js) in every model file. I assume that it will load the same db connection everytime as from the [Node.js docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#modules_caching):
every call to require('foo') will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.

As this is the first time I am coding in JS and asynchronous programming I am confused about few things. Will my same configuration file be loaded as I want to have a singleton kinda pattern for my db file. Is my approach correct ?

When I do - self.db.release() I assume I am releasing a connection back to the pool. But it's giving an error and I am unable to figure it out as everything else is working fine.The error is -

```
        self.db.release() is not a function
```

If I comment this line it's working fine. Is there a way to see what this release is returning as it will help in debugging.

Moreover is my approach correct.

Comment: The ``configuration.js`` returns a pool, not a connection itself. The pool has no ``release`` method. To make it work, you should get a connection from the pool and run the query on the connection - ``self.db.getConnection(function(err, connection) { connection.query()}``
and to close the connection  in the ``connection.query`` callback call the ``connection.release()``.

Comment: @tiblu that helped. Thanks. I should read the docs properly. Can you please suggest anything about my approach, any improvement.

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your approach. We can achieve the same result in several different ways, but by the end of the day the most important thing is to solve the problem feel good. Have fun!